# setting first android application

Tags: android

I was trying to run my first android app following a tutorial and found the next issue: according to the tutorial on the image provided I should be able to choose "Blank Activity" on the Create Activity window with the Create Activity checkbox checked but I can't go any further, if you see the image the "Finish" button is not available, I would have to unchecked the checkbox in order for the button to be available again which is wrong, is not supposed to work like that. If I uncheck the checkbox and choose finish I get an empty project and do not know how to proceed. Does any one knows what is happening or if this is a bug?. I know I can do an activity later on but right now just wanted to follow the tutorial as it is, any comments are welcome...
[image]

Comment: You need to update your sdk to higher version.Current version is 8,you need to update it to 14.

Comment: Your ADT version is hiigher as compare your SDK is not updated,

 please Update all tools and after try it with the restart your pc.

Answer (score 0):

Update your SDK from here
**Menu>Windows>Android SDK Manager**